# How is the link generated for automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, automation

Hello I have created list of automations on cloud page and want to generate link to each automation

Is there a way how to generate the link?

`https://mc.sx.marketingcloudapps.com/AutomationStudioFuel3/#Instance/UDh5MU1aYnh3MG1KMTlJV0FqemhsUToyNTow`

I want to know if I can dynamically provide the last part of the link

'UDh5MU1aYnh3MG1KMTlJV0FqemhsUToyNTow'

I have only figured that 'UToyNTow' is used in all automations url but they change with time as well

Marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the string I'm looking for is 'ID,' but I cannot retrieve it with the WS Proxy. I suppose this can only be retrieved via REST or SOAP.

Even when I add this 'ID' and compose a URL, unfortunately, it will not work.

EDIT:
when you use link as:

> mc.sx.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Automation%20Studio/AutomationStudioFuel3/%23Instance/UkJXeDl5OXNuVUt0N2NYSi12OWZEZzoyNTow/workflow

where **UkJXeDl5OXNuVUt0N2NYSi12OWZEZzoyNTow** is automation ID (retrievable only via API you can do it )